why is basic doctrine update not working?
I am building a basic CRUD but I can't make the Update to work. This is the code I have for the update:
$this->entityManager->persist($entityData);
$this->entityManager->flush();

$entityData contents:
$entityData = {App\Domain\Entity\User} 
 id = {resource} resource id='1026' type='stream'
 uuid = "8451e745-3a26-214e-b992-9bf1e47e46ee"
 name = "User #1 Name Updated"
 username = "UserNickName"
 email = "user_updated@domain.sandbox"
 password = "UserPasswordUpdated"
 description = "User description"

I have no errors or exceptions, the only output I have is on the log:
doctrine.DEBUG: Beginning transaction [] []

doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: UPDATE user SET name = ?, email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ? (parameters: array{"1":"User #1 Name Updated","2":"user_updated@domain.sandbox","3":"UserPasswordUpdated","4":null}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":16}) {"sql":"UPDATE user SET name = ?, email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?","params":{"1":"User #1 Name Updated","2":"user_updated@domain.sandbox","3":"UserPasswordUpdated","4":"[resource(stream)]"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":16}} []

doctrine.DEBUG: Committing transaction [] []
doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []

Note that the 4th parameter of "parameters" array is null. It's a mysql binary uuid. On "params" it is logged properly as a resource.
Which can be the problem? I am using mysql 8.4 and doctrine/dbal 3.8.4. I have debugged it step by step and I didn't see anything.
Thanks
Tried debugging it all and change package version with no results
